# Wordpress, dynamic title on custom page

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to set an individual title for a wordpress custom page so that every user gets a title depending on content displayed. I've tried this code before calling get_header(); but it's not changing the title.

Is there any way in doing this on the custom page code itself?

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'my_tpl_wp_title', 100 );
function my_tpl_wp_title($title) {
    $title = 'My new cool title';

    return $title;
}
```

Any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check with below code.

```
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', function ($title) {
    // Make any changes here
    $title = "Akshay shah";
    return $title;
}, 999, 1);
```